# The alphabet of a certain language contains 22 consonants and 11 vowels . Any string of these letters is a word in this language so long as

Tags: combinatorics

The alphabet of a certain language contains 22 consonants and 11 vowels . Any string of these letters is a word in this language so long as no two consonants are together and no letter is used twice .The alphabet is divided into $6$ (non-empty) subsets. Prove that the letters in at least one of these groups form  a word in the language .
The solution given on the book is as follows:

> There are $11$ more consonants than vowels in the alphabet . Therefore, if we add the differences between the number of consonants and the number of vowels in each of the subset these differences must sum to $11 $ . It follows that there must be atleast one subset in which their difference is less than $ 2 $ and the letters of this subset must form a word.

However, I didn't quite get the idea of the solution. The question also seems unclear to me for instance what does it mean by "The alphabet is divided into $6$ (non-empty) subsets"  .... I mean by alphabets do they mean the words? And also, only a finite number of words are possible with these condition? Does they mean putting all the possible words in $6$ subsets? But then again , how is that possible at all? I am not getting the idea of the solution .... I mean what does they mean by " It follows that there must be atleast one subset in which their difference is less than $ 2 $ and the letters of this subset must form a word." ...how are they drawing this conclusion...I am not getting the idea behind it...

Comment: The alphabet is defined in the question.

Comment: The alphabet is set of letters, not words. Let define function $F(A)$, which domain is set of all non-empty subsets of the alphabet, and value is difference between number of consonants and vowels. $F(alphabet)=22-11=11$. For non-intersecting subsets $F(A\cup B)=F(A)+F(B)$. Then for any division of the alphabet into six non-empty subsets $A_1, A_2, ... , A_6$: $F(A_1)+F(A_2)+F(A_3)+F(A_4)+F(A_5)+F(A_6) = 11 < 6\cdot 2$. Then at least one of $F(A_i)$ is less than 2. Then we can form a word using all the letters from corresponding subset $A_i$.

Comment: They mean placing all the letters in the six possible nonempty subsets.

Comment: The reason that it is critical for a subset of letters to exist, where the number of consonants is no more than $1 +$ the number of vowels is because a word formed from this subset of letters can begin and end with a consonant.  The presumption is that between the first and last letters of the constructed word, every other letter is a vowel.  This method of construction requires that the number of consonants in the word not exceed the number of vowels in the word by more than $(+1)$.

Comment: Re previous comment: possible syntax confusion: by the phrase "*every other letter is a vowel*", I intended that the vowels and consonants **alternate**.